# Encrypt and compress FileStream and save to same file

Tags: c#, stream, filestream

I have a method to compress and encrypt a stream.

```
private static void CompressThenEncrypt(string inputFileName, ICryptoTransform encryptor) 
{
    using (var inputFileStream = new FileStream(inputFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite)) 
    using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(inputFileStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
    using (var zipStream = new GZipStream(cryptoStream, CompressionMode.Compress)) 
    {
        inputFileStream.CopyTo(zipStream);
    }
}
```

Which does work, but it appends compressed and encrypted data to raw one I have in that file.

So if my file contains:

```
kkk
```

Then after compression and encryption it does look for example like that:

```
kkkㆆ鬁⠕⟶ꏙᇚ셑襜㷡ꕢ束৘㺝娥☪
```

Do anyone have any idea how to overwrite new data?

Comment: So you want to replace the content of a file with compressed and encrypted data? (You want compress/encrypt `kkk` and replace it in the file)

Comment: Exactly that's what I want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write to a temporary MemoryStream. Something like:

```
private static void CompressThenEncrypt(string inputFileName, ICryptoTransform encryptor) 
{
    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(inputFileName,FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
    using (var zipStream = new GZipStream(cryptoStream, CompressionMode.Compress)) 
    {
        fileStream.CopyTo(zipStream);
        cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
        fileStream.SetLength(0);
        memoryStream.Position = 0;
        memoryStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
    }
}
```

I think that should work, from the top of my head. Not sure you would have to set the length, and I'm not sure you can get away with not resetting the position of the MemoryStream. I haven't tested this code. If you are concerned about memory usage, you can always buffer the usage, but that would require more complicated code.

Comment: Using a memory stream would mean reading the entire file into memory.

Comment: This seems like a good idea. But I can't make it work. Tried to set memoryStream.Position to 0 as well, also tried to pass int in MemoryStream  constructor for some capacity. It just outputs empty file. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Try flushing the streams. Looking at the documentation for CopyTo, it does require you to set the position of the memoryStream. You can also try using WriteTo. I am unable to test the code currently, sorry, I can get back to you if you still don't get it to work.

Comment: @Magnus Obviously. And if you think such a solution is unsuited for your problem you shouldn't do it that way.

Comment: Still no luck. Tried setting up position at 0, WriteTo doesn't change a thing as well. Methinks that  the problem is with memoryStream which is empty and CopyTo() gives me System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Positive number required. Parameter name: bufferSize'

Comment: That happens when I try to send bytes array, which i made with memoryStream.GetBuffer();

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. What you need to do is call FlushFinalBlock() on the CryptoStream, as well as setting the position on the MemoryStream. I've updated my original answer with code that works for me when testing. Let me know if you don't get that working.

Comment: It does work! You're awesome! Sorry for late reply, but I wasn't around.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest:

1. Write to a new file
2. Delete the old file
3. Rename the new file to the old file.

Comment: That in fact does work, but is there any way to do it "on the fly" with just one FileStream?

Comment: I dont think it is possible to read and write and delete using the same stream. (In an easy way)

Comment: I dont actually think you current solution works if the size of the input is greater the the size of the buffer used in `CopyTo`